# Remove a file's "read only" attribute in vim after editing it and saving with :w!

Tags: linux, unix, vim, readonly

I want to change the read only attribute from a file when I save it with `:w!` in vim. How do I do it? (I don't mind if I have to call an external script).

I'm using Linux.

I know I can use an external script using this command: `autocmd BufWrite /tmp/* !sh /tmp/script.sh`. So, I would like to call a chmod command when `:w!` is invoked: the chmod command is going to be something like this:

```
autocmd BufWrite <:w! condition> !chmod u+w %
```

So, how do I do the ":w!" condition? Is it possible or do I need to use another structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The v:cmdbang is what you are looking for.

```
function! g:ChmodOnWrite()
  if v:cmdbang
    silent !chmod u+w %
  endif
endfunction

autocmd BufWrite * call g:ChmodOnWrite()
```

Comment: This is a REALLY neat solution, I've checked the cmdbang documentation http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#v:cmdbang to understand it's behavior. I knew vim would have something like this! Well done!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use just `*`:

```
autocmd BufWrite * !chmod u+w %
```

It may be better to use [`BufWriteCmd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#BufWriteCmd) instead.  I think that if the `chmod` fails, Vim will not attempt to write.

Comment: But isn't this command going to be called from every ":w" instead of just ":w!"?

Answer (score 0):

The shell command `chmod u+w <name of file>` does what you want.  I don't know offhand how to invoke that from inside vim.

Comment: I can use an external script using this command: autocmd BufWrite /tmp/* !sh /tmp/script.sh. I've edited my question with more information.